# Last pass through a loop behaving weird and implicit error on function call?

Tags: c, for-loop

my code:

```
#define RUNS 4

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i;
    int _length;
    float _totalTimeToReachLength;
    float _arrayOfTimes[RUNS - 1];
    float _sumDev = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < RUNS; i++)
    {
        float localHopNumber = GenerateHops(_length); //pass length into hops method.

        _arrayOfTimes[i] = localHopNumber; //add hop number generated to array.
        _sumDev = (_sumDev + (_arrayOfTimes[i]-(_totalTimeToReachLength / RUNS)) * (_arrayOfTimes[i]-(_totalTimeToReachLength / RUNS))); //work out sd.
        _totalTimeToReachLength = _totalTimeToReachLength + _arrayOfTimes[i];

        printf("Current increment for average: %f\n", _totalTimeToReachLength);
        printf("Item added to array: %f\n", _arrayOfTimes[i]);
    }

    printf("The standard deviation of times is: %f\n", sqrt(_sumDev/RUNS));
    printf("The standard average of times is: %f\n", _totalTimeToReachLength / RUNS);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is it messing up on the last loop?

Comment: "last loop"? I see only one loop.

Comment: Also, why the proliferation of underscores?!

Answer (score 5):

The array declaration needs to be:

```
float _arrayOfTimes[RUNS];
```

The declaration in the OP using `RUNS-1` declares it as an array of 3 elements (but you are storing 4 values in it).

Comment: Wouldn't [4] mean it has values at 0 1 2 3 4?

Comment: @dev6546 [4] gives it a length of 4.. 0 1 2 3

Comment: @dev6546:  No.  Giving it a size of [4] means it has array positions 0, 1, 2, 3.  The declaration size gives the number of elements, and they always start at zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `arrayOfTimes` with 3 floats. But in your loop, you are accessing upto 4. Thus invoking *undefined behaviour*.

Either change the condition to:
 `for (i = 0; i < RUNS -1; i++)`

Or `float _arrayOfTimes[RUNS-1];` to `float _arrayOfTimes[RUNS];`

Answer (score 0):

You're overrunning _arrayOfTimes.  You declare it with 3 elements but assign to element 4.

```
float _arrayOfTimes[RUNS - 1];  

_arrayOfTimes[i] = localHopNumber;
```